# Run Pex not in Right click menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pex

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Ultimate

Microsoft Moles   1.0.0.0
Moles generator for Visual Studio

I am in the process of doing some research/work with MS Pex/Moles and have downloaded version 0.94.0.0 of Pex/Moles.  The installation completed without any errors.

I am running through some of the documents that were included, one of which is Getting Started with Microsoft Code Contracts and Microsoft Pex.  I am running into issues with Exercise 1.  When I go to right click over in my method, the document says I should see a Run Pex option, but I dont' have the option. In fact, I don't have any options for Pex in the right click menu or anywhere else for that matter.

I ran the installer with VS closed and I also don't have a reference added for Pex (I did have it and it did not give me the option for Run Pex).

As a company, we are not yet moving to Vs2012, so that is not an option.

Updated:  I just downloaded the following:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/d2279651-851f-4d7a-bf05-16fd7eb26559/default.aspx
 which is 'Pex - Automated Whitebox Testing for .NET (32 bit)' even though I have a 64 bit machine.  I installed and then opened up my VS2010 again and tried.  I do have the option for Run Pex and Run Pex Exploration.  I am not sure if the original download didn't have this to install or if I needed to install separately.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the following: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/d2279651-851f-4d7a-bf05-16fd7eb26559/default.aspx which is 'Pex - Automated Whitebox Testing for .NET (32 bit)' even though I have a 64 bit machine. I installed and then opened up my VS2010 again and tried. I do have the option for Run Pex and Run Pex Exploration. I am not sure if the original download didn't have this to install or if I needed to install separately.